# How to use external django API data in html dropdown

Tags: html, json, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I have an API which gives me json data. I would like to get some values out of that json and list as a drop down on my HTML. Do I need to create a form for that.

For instance, I have a URL, http://netbox.com/api/deviceroles which gives a json file and I want to extract names out of it. deviceroles will consist of all the values of names.

views.py

```
import json, urlib
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET'
        url = "http://netbox.com/deviceroles"
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        for i in range (0, len (data['results'])):
            deviceroles = data['results'][i]['name']
    return render(request,"base.html")
```

base.html

```
<div class="em-c-field">
  <label for="file" class="em-c-field__label">Device Role</label>
   <div class="em-c-field__body">
    <select class="em-c-select em-c-select" id="file" placeholder="Placeholder">
    <optgroup>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">please select a device role</option>

    </optgroup>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Django's built-in templating you can do:

```
<select class="em-c-select em-c-select" id="file" placeholder="Placeholder">]
    {% for devicerole in deviceroles %}
    <optgroup>
        <option value="{{ devicerole }}" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">{{ devicerole }}</option>
    </optgroup>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

views.py to

```
import json, urlib
def home(request):
    deviceroles = list()
    if request.method == 'GET'
        url = "http://netbox.com/deviceroles"
        response = urllib.urlopen(url)
        data = json.loads(response.read())

        for i in range(0, len(data['results'])):
            devicerole = data['results'][i]['name']
            deviceroles.append(devicerole)
    return render(request,"base.html", {'deviceroles': deviceroles})
```

Comment: I tried that. But it is not showing any drop down. Is there any problem with the view?

Comment: Change this: return render(request,"base.html") to view return render(request,"base.html", {'data': data})

Comment: still not working. Am i using the get method properly. Also do I need to create a form for this.

Comment: Messed that up. Sorry. Change return render(request,"base.html", {'deviceroles': deviceroles})

Comment: Now it is showing the drop down. But showing only one name (last name in json list) and that to vertically and I was not able to select any thing

Comment: Your json data might only have one name. Html select/option is vertical. Once you click on an option you have selected the option.

Comment: I have multiple names in json file. that is why I am using this for loop,       
       "for i in range (0, len (data['results'])):
            deviceroles = data['results'][i]['name']". and vertical in the sense, it is showing each letter in that name as one column

Comment: Try the latest edit to views.py controller in my answer.